# Alternative to Count function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find an alternative for the count function for use in a VBA script,

I am trying to count the number of cells in an array and then use that value to define a for loop.

I have tried the following;

```
NoColdReadings = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNT('5. Summary Information'!R[-7]C[5]:R[90]C[5])"
NumberOfColdProbes = ActiveSheet.Range("L4").End(xlDown).Row

MsgBox NumberOfColdProbes


For i = 4 To (Sheets("4. Word Doc").Range("H36").Value + 4)

ColdProbe = Cells(i, 12).Value
ListofCold = ListofCold & ColdProbe & Sepr

Next
```

NoColdreadings returns False, and NumberOfColdProbes returns 101, which is the total size of the array.

Is there another way of counting the number of cells with results in an array inside of VBA?

PS. the data in the array I am trying to count has the following format;

```
=IFERROR(IF(M4<>"",INDEX($D$4:$D$102,MATCH(IFERROR(SMALL($E$4:$E$102,C4),""),$E$4:$E$102,0)),""),"")
```

and returns "130854" etc.

Comment: The RHS - `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNT('5. Summary Information'!R[-7]C[5]:R[90]C[5])"` is evaluated to TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: You can't chain assignments like that: `foo = bar = someExpression`, that gets evaluated as `foo = (bar = someExpression)`, i.e. `foo = {boolean}`, and there's your `False` value.

Comment: As for the row# being the last cell in the array, that's because you're using `.End(xlDown)` - start from the bottom of the sheet and use `.End(xlUp)` instead.

Comment: "count the number of cells in an array", an array does not contain cells. If you are using the number of array elements to "define a for loop", using `For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)` will define your loop. If you are trying to count the number of elements in the array that are values, the you have to loop though the array, test each element that is not empty, and add them using a counter.  Or just count the number of constants in the range you used to define the range array.